# How to convert SWT Image to data URI for use in Browser-widget

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to display images inside a Browser-widget (SWT). These images can be found inside the a jar file (plug-in development). However: this is not directly possible as the browser-widget expects some kind of URL or URI information.

My idea is to turn SWT-images into data-URI values, which I could induce into the src-attribute of every given img-element. I know, that this is not a good solution from a performance point of view, but I don't mind the speed disadvantage.

**I'd like to know how to turn a SWT image into a data-URI value for use in a browser-widget**.

My code so far:

```java
package editor.plugin.editors.htmlprevieweditor;

import editor.plugin.Activator;

import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class HtmlPreview extends Composite implements DisposeListener {

    private final Browser content;

    public HtmlPreview(final Composite parent, final int style) {
        super(parent, style);

        this.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        content = new Browser(this, style);
        final ImageData imageData = Activator.getImageDescriptor(Activator.IMAGE_ID + Activator.PREVIEW_SMALL_ID).getImageData();
        content.setText("<html><body><img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + imageData + "\"/></body></html>"); // need help on changing imageData to a base64-encoded String of bytes?

        this.addDisposeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void widgetDisposed(final DisposeEvent e) {
        e.widget.dispose();
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)!

Edit 1: I have read [SWT Image to/from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189025/swt-image-to-from-string) , but unfortunately it does not seem to exactly cover my needs.

Edit 2: I don't know if it matters, but I am trying to load a PNG24-image with per-pixel alpha-transparency.

Answer (score 2):

The question is too general if you only say "Browser in SWT". Mozzila browser supports `jar` URL protocol, and you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final URL url = ShellSnippet.class.getResource("/icons/full/message_error.gif");
    final Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.MOZILLA);
    final String html = String.format("<html><head/><body>image: <img src=\"%s\"/></body></html>", url);
    browser.setText(html);

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I used an image from the JFace jar to keep the snippet simple and yet work for most people out of the box. It is GIF, but I expect it to work just as well with PNG files.

If you use Internet Explorer, something I do not recommend because your application depends on OS version, this does not work. It looks like this (after changing in the snippet the style from SWT.MOZILLA to SWT.NONE):

[image]

It does however understand the `file` protocol and you can copy files to the temp folder and create URLs directly to the file using `File.toURL()`. This should work for any browser.

I cannot test the simple solution on WEBKIT broswer. If anyone can, please post the result in a comment.

Comment: I've read, that unless I specify SWT.MOZILLA and ensure xulrunner.exe to be on classpath, I cannot use Mozilla-Browser-widget on Windows-computers. This means it'd be quite difficult to use the mozilla-browser widget - even though I'd appreciate it, because of this support.
I will try it out! Thank you very much for this hint. As soon as I figured a way to use Mozilla-Browser-widget, I will mark this answer as the correct one unless someone provides a better answer.

Comment: @Igor In my case I just added: System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", "path to xulrunner"); And the xul runner is copied in "path to xulrunner".